# org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Template not found

Tags: templates, grails, jboss

I am using Grails 1.3.7 and deploy to JBoss 5.1.1. when I try to access a page myPage.gsp in one of the plugins. I got the Template not found error.

the page is working ok when using grails run-app. and the template file are definitely in th correct location and it is NOT missing.

I had searched around this issue, there is nothing really out there. I am new to Grails, I cant understand why this file is not found as it is there.

File structure as following:

- grailsPlugins

  - myplugin
  - grails-app

    - views
    - templates

      - _myTemplate.gsp
    - mypages

      - myPage.gsp

in the `myPage.gsp`, I have a line like this:

```
<g:render template="/templates/myTemplate"/>
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: I have it sorted, added optional attribute plugin="myplugin" for the g:render tag, now the problem sorted

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this same issue before, so just for reference for others, while adding the optional attribute `plugin="myplugin"` works to resolve the plugin location, it won't allow the application that installs the plugin to customize the `myTemplate` template(if there is ever a need to as there was in my case!)

I found that copying the templates over to the application on install or via a script, just like Spring Security copies login template when you run the `s2-quickstart` was the easiest way to completely resolve the issue.